# Conditionals in tsx-files (React + TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, reactjs

We have been using React and jsx for a while, and for conditionals we have been using jsx-control-statements which I really like:

```
<If condition={something === true}>
    <div>Something</div>
</If>
```

Recently our project has moved on to TypeScript, which is nice, but jsx-control-statements no longer work. The reason is that the conditional expressions are not React components, but are handled by Babel in the transpilation step, which means that TypeScript won't compile.

What are my options?

I thought about making an If-component, but it would require me to wrap the result in a new element, which I don't like.

Comment: The difference is that implementing the conditionals as React components we would have to wrap the contents of the statement in an extra element. Also, not having to re-implement what jsx-control-statements already does well is nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't provide enough information what is not working for you, but I guess it has something to do with the fact that [`jsx-control-statements`](https://github.com/AlexGilleran/jsx-control-statements) is a babel plugin rather than a library with additional JSX elements.

To make it work with TypeScript you need to:

(1) Add declaration files/typings for the globally available elements. E.g. something like:

```
declare function If (condition: any): any;
declare var Choose: any;
declare function When (condition: any): any;
declare var Otherwise: any;
```

(2) In your `tsconfig.json` set `jsx` to `preserve`. You can also set the target to ES2015 and let babel do the work.

(3) Use babel + plugins to transpile your JSX. It's very likely your configuration from before the switch to TypeScript works.

*I am not using the jsx-control-statements myself. So the above might not necessary work correctly and you have to do additional steps.*

Comment: I prefer option 2-3, let babel work as before with jsx.

Comment: That's steps not options, I guess. :D Because TypeScript doesn't know the `<If>` JSX element for example.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the vague description. My problem was, as you figured, that TypeScript wouldn't compile since it did not recognize the statements. Step 1 solved the problem, I believe step 2 and 3 were already in place :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation at my current job - codebase written with `jsx-control-statements` that I want to migrate to typescript, so I've started developing a [typescript compiler plugin](https://github.com/KonstantinSimeonov/tsx-control-statements) which aims to be a drop-in replacement for `jsx-control-statements`.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me:

```
// global.d.ts
declare const If: React.FC<{ condition: boolean }>
declare const Choose: React.FC
declare const When: React.FC<{ condition: boolean }>
declare const Otherwise: React.FC

// .eslintrc
"extends": [
  'plugin:jsx-control-statements/recommended',
],
"rules": {
  "react/jsx-no-undef": [ "error", { "allowGlobals": true } ],
  // This rule doesn't work with typescript.
  // It reports code like `ReturnType<typeof something>` 
  // as `'something' is not defined`.
  "jsx-control-statements/jsx-jcs-no-undef": "off",
}
```

I didn't add definitions for `<With>` and `<For>`, because no idea how to make it fully compatible with TS. And I personally consider these tags more harmful than useful.